# Python tkinter encoder which but the programme is so long

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, encoder

So the idea is making an encoder i mean when user write for example "a" in label called text the programme paste result for ex "}" and so on.

The question is do i have to write "if" for every letter in alphabet and  every place in the label text i mean if user_code[0]
if user_code[1]
and so on

```
import tkinter as tk

#making main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Szyfrator")
root.geometry("600x300")

#getting text
def getting_Text():
    user_code = text.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    if user_code[0] == 'a' :
       result.insert(tk.END, '[', 'big')
    if user_code[0] == 'b':
        result.insert(tk.END, ';', 'big')
#UX of the window
right_margin = tk.Frame(root)
right_margin.pack (side=tk.RIGHT, expand =tk.YES , fill=tk.BOTH)
left_margin = tk.Frame(root)
left_margin.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
#after clicking button function getting_text() is used
button = tk.Button( root , text = "Szyfruj", activebackground = "#FFFFFF", command=getting_Text)
button.pack( side = tk.TOP )
text=tk.Text(root, width=36, height=15 )
text.pack(side= tk.LEFT)
result= tk.Text(root, width=36, height=15 )
result.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


#  ):


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can use a for-loop to iterate over the letters of `user_code`, and create a dictionary to map a letter to another.

```py
encoded = {
    "a": "[",
    "b": ";"
}

def getting_Text():
    user_code = text.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    for letter in user_code:
        try:
            result.insert(tk.END, encoded[letter], 'big')
        except KeyError: # if we don't have an encoding for a letter, a KeyError will be raised which we capture
            print("Oops, no encoding found for letter %s" % letter)
```

And if you have many different letter encodings and don't want to type in so much commas, quotes, colons, you can even create the dictionary like this:

```py
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" # letters and encodings must have the same amount of symbols, else it may give you an IndexError: index out of range
encodings = "[;]:_-#'+*´`?=)(/&%$§!°^<>"
encoded = {key: value for key, value in zip(list(letters), list(encodings))}
```

Comment: i literally love you men, thank you so much,

Comment: @Kyle2115 no problem ! :)